# OpenGapps using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I am using Android Studio 3.4.1 and trying to get an Android OS that both has **Google Play** as well as **allow rooting** via `adb`. Seems very difficult to accomplish this task. Either I can get an image with Google Play services and it cannot be rooted, or I can get an image with Google APIs and cannot get Google Play installed.

I have downloaded the OpenGapps package from opengapps.org, but a lot of the articles I have read on pushing this to the emulator seems extremely confusing. For one, I don't have an $ANDROID_HOME variable and the directory that I've seen for setting it manually **does not exist**.

**Second Attempt**

I've tried to use `adb push` and only gotten "Access denied" errors. I can confirm that I can get a root shell by doing `adb root`, followed by `adb shell`, and then `whoami`.

```
[root@mbp.local:~/Downloads]$ adb shell                                                                                                                   6:18PM/06.19
generic_x86:/ # whoami
root
generic_x86:/ #
```

Here's what happens when I try to adb push onto the SD card (I believe this is the SD card volume at least):

```
[root@mbp.local:~/Downloads]$ adb push open_gapps-x86-9.0-stock-20190618.zip /mnt/media_rw/1CFC-3313/Android/data                                         6:18PM/06.19
adb: error: failed to copy 'open_gapps-x86-9.0-stock-20190618.zip' to '/mnt/media_rw/1CFC-3313/Android/data/open_gapps-x86-9.0-stock-20190618.zip': remote fchown failed: Operation not permitted
open_gapps-x86-9.0-stock-20190618.zip: 0 files pushed. 192.6 MB/s (1965840 bytes in 0.010s)
```

**Third Attempt**

The next thing I tried to do was just simply drag and drop the .zip file onto the Android Emulator, and that didn't work either:

[image: Drag & Drop onto Android Emulator]

**Fourth Attempt**

Next, I tried to download OpenGapps from the website itself from within the Android Emulator, but it seems that it never finishes downloading. It just hangs at 98% although it only takes me a few seconds to nearly complete the download:

[image: Attempt to download from web interface]

All I want to accomplish is getting an Android image with Google Play services that I can root. I figured by at least having an Android image that I can root, I can just simply install GApps afterwards, but I can't seem to get there.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.